# scriptaculous sortable tree - prevent nodes from entering child/parent lists

Tags: javascript, html, scriptaculous

Working on an old project that is using scriptaculous and running into an issue. I currently have a tree structure like the following:

```
Item 1
  + Item 1a
    + Item 1aa
    + Item 1ab
  + Item 1b 
Item 2
  + Item 2a
  + Item 2b
    + Item 2ba
    + Item 2bb
```

With the way I have the sorting setup now using the tree option, the user is able to drag **Item 2bb** into **Item 2a** which I am trying to prevent. I would like to keep dragged items within their parent category. So if **Item 2ba** exists under **Item 2b**, the user should not be able to drag the item outside of that parent. The create code that I am using is VERY simple:

```
Sortable.create('cats', {tree:true,scroll:window,treeTag:'ul',tag:'li', onChange:function(){$('save-cats').style.visibility='visible';}});
```

and the structure consists of standard `<li>` tags (notice the nested `<ul>` tags:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>
   Item 2
   <ul>
      <li>Item 2a</li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Is this even possible with scriptaculous, or do I have to upgrade to something else?

I forgot to mention that this is a dynamic list. I don't know if the containment option is what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem possible because I won't have unique ids.

### UPDATE

It this helps, I've been toying with the following code:

```
new Draggable('cats',{revert:true});

    Droppables.add('cats', { 
    onDrop: function(element) 
            {
                return false;
            }});
```

cats is the ID of the main ul element. the onDrop is firing, but I can't get it to revert back or "not accept" the item. I am assuming that if I can do that, I can compare the current parent with the new parent, and if they are not the same, push the element back.